# return values from lambdas with auto parameter

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, c++14

I am playing with lambda expressions and I am using `auto` as input parameter.

I did try this code below

```
auto f2 = [](auto a){ return a;};
std::cout << f2(10) << std::endl;
std::cout << f2("hi there!") << std::endl;
```

With my big surprise it compiles and run ok! How is that possible?

If I am not wrong (this comes with the C++14) the `operator()` of the function object is template since it uses `auto` as input parameter.

How does it manage multiple return types? First line returns an `int` and the second line returns `const char*`.

Is the compiler creating multiple  `operator()` behind the scenes?

Comment: How would you write that lambda as a function template?

Comment: I don't think the standard mandates how function objects should be implemented. Ie, they are not restricted to relying on templates or old-style functors.

Comment: _Is the compiler creating multiple `operator()` behind the scenes?_ Yes, a function template creates a different function each time it is instantiated with a different template argument. The lambda isn't doing anything special.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As you say, the `operator()` of generic lambda is effectively a function template. Something similar to:

```
struct noname
{
    template<typename T>
    auto operator ()(T a) const { return a; }
};
```

Your separate calls instantiate two different functions.

```
auto operator ()(int a) const { return a; }
auto operator ()(const char* a) const { return a; }
```

From there, the rules of `auto` return type apply. In the first function, the first and only return statement returns an `int`, therefore `int` is deduced as the return type. Same for `const char*`